# MySQL : rename primary key column which is foregin key to another table

Tags: python, mysql

I have a 2 table in mysql databse:

```
Personnel:
   personnel_id (PK)
   name
   age


qualification:
  qualification_id (PK)
  personnel_id (FK)
  clg name
  schl name
```

How can I rename a PK of personnel table(personnel_id)? As it is serving as Fk of qualification table, while i rename that personnel_id I'm facing issue like:

"**Cannot change column 'personnel_id': used in a foreign key constraint 'qualification_ibfk_1' of table 'mobilemeta.qualification**"

```
 A possible way that I know is:
     Drop FK, Rename Column, Add FK
```

But I'm handling these **database operations using python**. So it is not possible to find to which table it is referenced as the foreign key, is there any way to handle it dynamically?

Any solutions?

Comment: Drop foreign key. Rename column. Create foreign key.

Comment: I'm handling these database operations using python. So it is not possible to find to which table it is referenced as the foreign key, is there any way to handle it dynamically? @Artem Bozhko

Comment: As described here https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/102371/how-to-check-foreign-keys-related-to-a-table you can query information about usage of your column in constraints and then dynamically drop and recreate them. @Aishu

Comment: Thanks, it worked. @Artem Bozhko

Answer (score 0):

You can follow do like this to get it done.

**OPTION 1 :**

```
SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=0;
<Your first alter command to rename the primary key in "Personnel" table>;
<Your second alter command to change the foreign key in "qualification" table>;
SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=1;
```

**OPTION 2**

Alternatively, you can

1. Drop the foreign key of "qualification" table
2. Rename the primary key in "Personnel" table
3. Redefine the foreign key

Answer (score 0):

use alter command for change column name 
and donot need change foreign or primary key.
simply change name use alter command
ALTER TABLE table_name
modify column name old name new name datatype

Comment: I've tried, but it does not allow me to change because it is serving as FK to another Table.

Comment: why are you show specificaly foregn key donot mention any column as foregn key just mention primary key ok remove foregn key just simply use primary key to another but not mention as a foregin ok and change column name because no need foregn key for joins or other query